# Pandas: Join data to a single row to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I'm new to pandas and have been having trouble using the `merge`, `join` and `concatenate` functions on a single row of data.

I'm iterating over a handful of rows in a table and in each iteration add some data I've found to the row I'm handling. I know, blasphemy! Thou shall not iterate. Each iteration results in a call to a server, so I need to control flow. There aren't that many rows. It's just for my own use. I promise I'll not iterate when I shouldn't.

That aside, my basic question is this: How do I add data to a given row where the new data has priority over existing data and has new columns?

Let's suppose I have a DataFrame `df` that I'm iterating over by row:

```
> df
  c1 c2 c3
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
```

and when iterating on row 0, I get some new data that I want to add to row 0. That new data is in `df_a`:

```
> df_a
  c4 c5 c6
0  g  h  i
```

I want to add data from `df_a` to row 0 of `df` so `df` is now:

```
> df
  c1 c2 c3  c4  c5  c6
0  a  b  c   g   h   i
1  d  e  f NaN NaN NaN
```

Next I iterate on row 1 and I get some columns which overlap and some which don't in `df_b`:

```
> df_b
  c5 c7 c8
0  j  k  l
```

And again I want to add this data to row 1 so `df` now has

```
> df
  c1 c2 c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8
0  a  b  c   g   h   i NaN NaN
1  d  e  f NaN   j NaN   k   l
```

I can't list columns names because I don't know what they'll be and new ones can appear beyond my control. Rows don't have a key because the whole thing gets thrown away after I disconnect. Data I find during each iteration always overwrites what's currently in `df`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t iterate over a dict and then insert the result into a dataframe?

Comment: Can you explain further? If I interate over a dict instead of a dataframe, I may still have to add columns to the dataframe because each iteration might reveal columns I didn't know about before the current iteration. I guess I could do all of the iteration in advance where each iteration produces a separate dataframe with different columns? Then concatenate all of those to a new dataframe with a list of unique columns? Seems like a lot of hoops though.

Comment: If you need access to the dataframe on each iteration, then my suggestion might not work. But if you don't, dicts are easier to work with

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I couldn't access the data frame on each iteration, it'd get quite messy and maybe I'd be better of just sticking with a dictionary then. But with all the power of pandas, it seems like adding my use case should be easier. But I understand it isn't one pandas targets.

Comment: How do you know to which row you have to append the new data?

Comment: I append data to the row I'm currently iterating on, eg `index`, `row` from `iterrows`